# can't write to /dev/bus/usb/001/005

Tags: raspbian, usb

I am running raspbian, and trying to send data to a Zebra thermal printer, which is connected via USB.

I type

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat > /dev/bus/usb/001/005
OEPL1
```

and I get:

```
cat: write error: Invalid argument
```

And it appears that the data was not in fact written (I would know because if it were, the light on the printer would blink). **What should I do to write data directly to the device?**

Here is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5f:0015 Zebra
```

Here is the relevant output of `dmesg`:

```
[    3.193293] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.309444] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5f, idProduct=0015
[    3.319280] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=4, SerialNumber=6
[    3.329169] usb 1-1.3: Product: LP2824
[    3.336240] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Zebra ;
[    3.342888] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 22J091300968
```

Comment: Have you tried `echo` -- e.g. `echo OEPL1 > /dev/bus/whatever`?  This adds a newline, you can disable that with `-n`.

Comment: Agreed with goldilocks, you should be `echo`ing text to the device, not using `cat`.

Comment: No, `echo` does the same thing as `cat` (I don't see why it would be different). `echo OEPL1 > 005` produces `-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

Comment: Closed for now because this doesn't appear to be Raspberry Pi-specific.  If someone has a reason this might be specific to the Raspberry Pi, we can reopen this.

Comment: The exact same problem does not occur on other distros of Linux or other hardware. It is specific to raspbian on raspberry pi.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK, probably you want to send direct commands to your printer, that means ZPL in your case. Writing directly to that file (/dev/bus/usb/001/005) will not work, I tried chmod 777 and sudo on that file but it just doesn't work. From what I understand only on some old versions of linux you could write directly to that file, now is not permitted anymore.

I am using an Intermec printer, an appropriate solution for me was to install my printer using CUPS and then I used the cups command lp to send data to my printer:

```
lp -d printer_name -o raw file_name
```

You could send this command from C using the *system* function from *stdlib.h*

Comment: You should try to provide a little more detail as to how to do this. You might even want to add a link that includes additional details.

Comment: I was able to set up the device this way, which solves my problem, so I'm marking this correct. However, it does not answer the question, which is how to send data directly to the USB device. CUPS does this somehow: what C code do I have to write to accomplish the same thing?